# Python Count per quantiles and pre set quartiles

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, quartile

I want to know if there is a code wherein I can count how many in my dataset goes to 25%, 50%, 75% and if there is a way to adjust the quartiles manually like 20% 40% 60% 80%, etc.

```py
Out[1]: 
              ALC (mins)
       count  303.000000
       mean   24.928812
       std    18.316443
       min    3.120000
       25%    12.680000
       50%    20.770000
       75%    30.535000
       max    143.180000
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `percentiles` optional argument:

```
>>> df.describe(percentiles = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8])
           (mins)
count    8.000000
mean    69.566282
std    104.255870
min      3.120000
20%     14.934577
40%     20.279289
50%     22.849406
60%     26.050050
80%     98.122000
max    303.000000
```

For counting how much elements will per quartile:

```
np.linspace(1, len(df), 5, dtype = np.int64)  # division by 5 since it starts from min, to 25%, 50%, 75%, then max.
```

Comment: is there a way to count how many data i have for the 20%, 40% etc.?

Comment: @RollyV. Modified the answer.